# Same navigation types one more in EF 4.1

Tags: c#, .net, code-first, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am a little confused about below entity relations. Because it holds User relation one than more. I am feeling that there is something wrong. Is there anything wrong about it ?

```
public class Subject: Entity
{
    public Advert()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public virtual User Owner{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Voters{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<User> Followers{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will apply to you Lists, which should be ICollections for EF CodeFirst standards.

you may also want to use inheritance to differentiate different types of users or have different entities for the followers and for the voters.

You need to map this using the WithMany()

this will allow you to specify the foreignKey for the relationship

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.BillingAddress)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.BillingAddressId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.DeliveryAddress)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.DeliveryAddressId);
}
```

Comment: What do you think about separation List<User> Voters into new Entity named Vote which has User Voter property?

Comment: well you could then have the vote value (positive negative) + the user (voter)